# Connecting S5 for debugging without USB

Tags: android

I have a dilemma in that I have just bought a Galaxy S5 to debug my Android apps on, but I've just discovered my work computer has disabled write access to USB for security, so I cannot connect the S5 via that method. Is there any other way I can debug on my S5 given this limitation?

Comment: If you use another computer to put it in ADB wifi mode you can do that until it fails or restarts, at which point you will need the USB cable to repeat that process.  But realistically, you are going to have to have engineering management explain to IT management that a functional USB port is a **requirement** for your project.  Perhaps you can get a linux box only for Android work, and keep it fairly distinct from the rest of your corporate systems/software.

Comment: You can use adb over tcp http://stuffandtech.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html